# Mac cant install socket.io with npm/nodejs?

Tags: macos, node.js, socket.io

I have been searching for hours now and I still have no answer for this problem.
I have mac os x version 10.6.8
I installed nodejs from nodejs.org. Version is v0.6.14.
I did this in terminal to check npm: npm --version. npm version is 1.1.12
after that I tried npm install socket.io and I got this error...

```
pm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.6.7
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.6.7
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.2.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.2.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5

> ws@0.4.11 preinstall /Users/NAME/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> make

execvp(): No such file or directory

npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/NAME/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/uglify-js/test/unit/compress/test/array1.js'
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 10.8.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "socket.io"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/NAME
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.14
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.12
npm ERR! path /Users/NAME/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/uglify-js/test/unit/compress/test/array1.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! message ENOENT, open '/Users/NAME/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/uglify-js/test/unit/compress/test/array1.js'
npm ERR! errno {}

npm ERR! ws@0.4.11 preinstall: `make`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "make"` failed with 127
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ws@0.4.11 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ws package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     make
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ws
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 10.8.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "socket.io"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/NAME
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.14
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! message ws@0.4.11 preinstall: `make`
npm ERR! message `sh "-c" "make"` failed with 127
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/NAME/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

PLS help!

Comment: Same error here on Mac OSX 10.6.8 ..

Answer (score 1):

Force the installation using

```
npm install socket.io -f
```

Looks like the tests needs node-waf, but not the library directly. I hope they fix these issues eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io runs a make upon install and requires node-waf in order to run.  Did you install node via a package manager like ports, or did you use the dmg install on the node website?

This thread speaks to the issue you're having:

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/773

Comment: I installed node-v0.6.14.pkg from nodejs.org. So I guess I installed it with a package manager?

But how do I fix the error? I need nodejs-dev to get node-waf?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like if you install an earlier version of `socket.io` there is no need to run the `make` script. I tried the following and managed to get it installed successfully on my Mac OSX 10.6.8:

```
npm install socket.io@0.7
```

There is further discussion on [this google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/socket_io/RTg2M4O6zag).